# Export and import accessibility settings for multiple persons under one user in Windows 10

Tags: setup, default-settings

I work with individuals with various physical and learning disabilities. Due to rules at work, *I can not create a separate user for each individual.* However, they all use different keyboard and mouse settings on Windows 10 Home.

Is there a way for me to create a link on the desktop or save their individual settings to make it quicker to change the settings when I swap users?

The settings most frequently changed are:

- Pointer size
- Pointer Speed
- Pointer visibility
- Sticky keys
- Filter keys
- Repeat keys

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  **:-)** Yes, that's possible by exporting the registry keys for all those settings to a file and then importing them again.  However, that might still violate the rules at work though as it'll be still user-based.  **¯\\_(ツ)_/¯**

Comment: Thankyou. The rules at work are set by some one whoho struggles to turn his computer on. I'm not much better but unfortunately still the most competent in the building so it is literally the blind leading the blind. I've got a bit of learning to do to use your solution but looks managable. And too complicated for him to have an issue. And hopefully means I don't spend 15 minutes setting up the computer everything some one new wants a turn. Any pointers on where to start learning would be greatly appreciated. But I'm heading straight to good old Google and YouTube. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for the acceptance!  Favour returned and question upvoted!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the Accessibility settings can be found under the [registry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry) key `HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility\` the Cursors under the `HKCU\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Cursors` key, ... so we're going to export all those and make it easy to import them back into said registry.

#### To create the SaveSettings CMD file:

1. Open Notepad and copy-paste the following code into it:

   ```
   @ECHO OFF
   REG export HKCU\Control Panel\Accessibility %userprofile%\desktop\SettingsA.reg /y
   REG export HKCU\Control Panel\Cursors %userprofile%\desktop\SettingsC.reg /y
   COPY %userprofile%\desktop\SettingsA.reg+%userprofile%\desktop\SettingsC.reg %userprofile%\desktop\Settings.reg
   DEL %userprofile%\desktop\SettingsA.reg
   DEL %userprofile%\desktop\SettingsC.reg
   ```
2. Save the file on the desktop as `SaveSettings.CMD` and exit Notepad
3. Click the Start button, type `cmd.exe` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. A black screen will open
5. Copy-paste the following commands in there:

   ```
   ren Desktop\SaveSettings.CMD.txt SaveSettings.CMD
   exit
   ```

The black window will disappear and from now on, you're all set to save the accessibility settings on the desktop per user and the above should be repeated for every computer you want this to be on.

#### To save the individual's settings:

1. First set all settings to their required values as you normally do.
2. Double-click the "SaveSettings" icon on your screen
3. A new icon will appear on the desktop
4. **Immediately** rename this file to the individual's name.

#### To import these settings in the future:

Well, just simply double-click the user's name and press "yes" to the warning and presto: **All settings for this user have been restored!**

## :-)

Comment: Please try above *on one computer first* and feed back as we might have to add more commands to the SaveSettings file depending on the actual settings you're going to change...